# Problem reinstalling ros indigo

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and had previously installed ros indigo. I uninstalled it with

```
sudo apt-get purge ros-indigo*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then tried the steps in the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) to install it again, did all the steps but when I get to

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

this comes up

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to install ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280562/problem-reinstalling-ros-indigo/) by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to still think you have ros-indigo-desktop, ros-indigo-perception, ros-indigo-simulators and ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial installed or something related to those. I suppose your purge didn't work entirely. Try and delete them again through a sudo apt-get remove packagename?

If that fails, you can try and do a sudo apt-get install -f (attempt to fix any broken packages). And then try to run your install again or try to delete them again and try the install again after that.

---

Originally posted by [JamesDoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30501/jamesdoe/) with karma: 78 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0